# Font configuration rule priority

Tags: fonts, configuration

If I have two files in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`.

One being:

```
<fontconfig>
<alias>
 <family>sans-serif</family>
 <prefer>
   <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
 </prefer>
</alias>
</fontconfig>
```

And the other one being:

```
<fontconfig>
<alias>
 <family>sans-serif</family>
 <prefer>
   <family>Noto Emoji</family>
 </prefer>
</alias>
</fontconfig>
```

What would the outcome be after they are both read in?

Reason behind the question --
I have a huge and messy font-selection file. If I can somehow build the font selection from files step by step, that'll be hugely tidy up my messy font-selection file. So,

Using the Noto Emoji as an example, how can I build my font selection step by step so that `Noto Color Emoji` is the default and `Noto Emoji` is the fallback?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number prepending the file name. For instance:

```
10-my-color.conf
20-my-other.conf
```

That should give the Color variant higher precedence.

P.S. Have you considered to use the `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d` directory for the purpose? That way you wouldn't mix your own files with the files installed by various packages.

Comment: Thx. Can you use concrete examples and also explain _"what would the outcome be after they are both read in?"_ please? As for the P.S. question, I'd rather do the configuration in one place for all people rather than a dozen of places for each of them. It's my personal choice. Moreover, the priority and ordering will be more complicated in that case.

Comment: @xpt: Well, I tried to answer your question, but I'm not going to write a general fontconfig tutorial. If you haven't already, I think you should learn how to use the `fc-match` command to study the outcome of the current configuration. And if you get stuck in how to make use of `fc-match` for this purpose, please ask a new question which focuses on that. Another thing is that I'm not convinced that splitting it into multiple files is a good idea. Maybe you should ask an open question with an example of what it is you want to achieve and ask for suggestions on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

`alias` element of `fontconfig` support a fallback/priority  list with default selection. No need for multiple files or alias rules. One alias rules should be enough for single family  match.

From fontconfig manpage:

> **`<alias>`**
>
> ```
> Alias elements provide a shorthand notation for the set of common
> match operations needed to substitute one font family for another.
>
> They contain a <family> element followed by optional <prefer>,
> <accept> and <default> elements. Fonts matching the <family>
> element are edited to prepend the list of <prefer>ed families
> before the matching <family>, append the <accept>able families
> after the matching <family> and append the <default> families to
> the end of the family list.
> ```
>
> **`<family>`**
>
> ```
> Holds a single font family name
> ```
>
> **`<prefer>`, `<accept>`, `<default>`**
>
> ```
> These hold a list of <family> elements to be used by the <alias>
> element.
> ```

Here your example with extended setup:

```
<fontconfig>
 <alias>
  <family>sans-serif</family>
  <!-- <accept> list if needed -->
  <prefer>
   <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
   <family>Noto Emoji</family>
   <!-- you may add more font families here -->
  </prefer>
  <!-- <default> list if needed -->
 </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

If you want to force the font bypass matching use `accept` instead.

By the way, you may take/think priority of `<prefer>` as medium/prefered, `<accept>` as strong/override, `<default>` as weak/fallback.

Here are a good examples: [Beyond Linux® From Scratch (System V Edition) - Overview of Fontconfig](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/tuning-fontconfig.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and helpful link, but the point that I want to build my font selection step by step is that I don't want my font-selection file to be huge and messy, or to mess into the font-selection file distributed by the system. Thus I need to break them into different files. That's the key point of the question.

Comment: @xpt okey then who you want isolate from system fontconfig, the user or an application?

Comment: The purpose / rule of thumb is, I want to 1) keep font-selection file distributed by the system as is, 2) keep font-selection file that I borrowed elsewhere as is, 3) keep my font-selection file as simple as possible, *only* contains the parts that *override* the settings from either borrowed or system default ones.